# getting java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to run nutch from eclipse with a cassandra datastore

Tags: java, eclipse, cassandra, nutch

I am trying to run apache nutch from eclipse with cassandra on Windows. This is the error i am getting.

```
InjectorJob: starting at 2017-02-17 17:35:42
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: C:/Users/STAN/Desktop/trunk/urls/seeds.txt
InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraStore as the Gora storage class.

    InjectorJob: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:774)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:646)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:434)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:281)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
        at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:115)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:246)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:267)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:299)
```

Answer (score 0):

InjectorJob: `Injecting urlDir: C:/Users/STAN/Desktop/trunk/urls/seeds.txt`

According to me this should be a directory not a file.

Comment: i have the same error even it's a directory. i also tried to use absolute path, either!